# How does ssh port forwarding work exactly

Tags: ssh-tunnel

I have the following setup:
One machine with sshd running (*local*) behind a router (router) and a second host (remote) tries to access *local* through the internet and the router via ssh.

Therefor: Port forwarding *router*:22 -> *local*:22 (and *router* as gateway for *local*) . Works perfectly fine.

If I try to create a ssh tunnel from *remote* to *local* as follows:

```
ssh -L 1234:R:12345 user@R
```

this will only work if I also redirect *router*:1234 -> *local*:1234.

My understanding was, that ssh will tunnel all the traffic trough its connection on port 22. But it seems, that this is not the case. Am I doing something wrong? Is there any possibility to tunnel all the traffic through a single connection?

Comment: There are multiple good answers below, I also wrote a blog post a while back covering this, so you may check it out.  Oh, it was 11 years ago! https://dmitry.khlebnikov.net/2010/12/10/ssh-port-forwarding-intermediate/

Answer (score 2):

Your question was a little unclear to me, so I'm going to specify what I assumed and then try and help you with your problem. You are at the computer 'remote' which is SSH'ing to 'local' and this part works fine. If this is the case we no longer need to worry about router.

Continuing my assumptions, 'local' has a service running on it on port 12345 that you would like to access from 'remote' without opening additional ports on your router. What you would want to do is use the following command from 'remote':

```
ssh -L 1234:localhost:12345 user@router's_ip
```

To connect to the service you would then access it through localhost:1234.

The way the port forwarding syntax works is: {**local_port**}:{**proxy_dest**}:{**proxy_port**}

**local_port** is the port that will open on the client machine you are connecting from, to access it you would use localhost:**local_port**

**proxy_dest** is the host you would like to connect to from the perspective of the server you are SSH'ing into

**proxy_port** is the port on the remote system that you would like to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to the second part of your question.  You can use the dynamic proxy feature of later versions of SSH to forward all traffic with a couple of caveats.

The applications you are using on your client must support SOCKS proxies.

The OpenSSH only supports a SOCKS4 style proxy.

The syntax used is:

ssh -D user@remotehost

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're wanting:

- To ssh from `remote` to `local`
- and forward port `1234` on remote to port `12345` on `local`

You seem to be indicating that `local` sits behind NAT happening on `router` - this would be why you need to set up the portforward so that `router:22` forwards internally to `local:22`

If I've understood this correctly, the commandline you want to use on remote is actually:

`ssh -L 1234:local:12345 user@router`

The key here is that although this is a `local` portforward (`-L` == `local`) the resolution of the hostname (ie, `local` in this case - the second parameter in the `1234:local:12345` list) happens on the destination machine - which in this case is `local`.

In your example, you had `1234:router:12345` - which means that traffic goes down the ssh tunnel from `remote` to `local`; then is routed from `local` to `router` - and as you've said, this requires yet another portforward to get the traffic back to `local`.

---

An alternative would be to ssh from `local` to `remote`, using `ssh -R 1234:local:12345`. This wouldn't need the portforward on `router`, but you'd still have `1234` on `remote` forward to `12345` on `local`. The obvious downside to this is that you can't initiate this connection from `remote`, as you have no way of reaching `local`.