# Having trouble redirecting frevvo using mod_proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, mod-proxy, confluence

This question is similar to this:

[How to access webservers running on ports blocked on company's network?](https://serverfault.com/questions/102868/how-to-access-webservers-running-on-ports-blocked-on-companys-network)

Basically, I'm using confluence and a plugin called frevvo. Confluence sits on port 8080 while frevvo sits on port 8082. I want to redirect both of them to port 80 via Apache HTTP web server so that it doesn't get blocked by company proxies.

I've been using the document on Atlassian that shows me how to run confluence behind Apache (I can't post a second URL due to being a newbie here)

I've successfully redirected Confluence from port 8080 to port 80 so I can now access Confluence using `www.example.com/confluence.`

Now I tried doing the same thing to frevvo with the following configurations:

Apache httpd:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /confluence http://localhost:8080/confluence
ProxyPassReverse /confluence http://localhost:8080/confluence
<Location /confluence>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Location>

ProxyPass /frevvo http://localhost:8082/
ProxyPassReverse /frevvo http://localhost:8082/
<Location /forms>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Location>
```

And in server.xml for the frevvo Tomcat instance, I added the following within `<Host>` tag:

```
<Context path=" " docBase="" debug="0" reloadable="false">
                    <!-- Logger is deprecated in Tomcat 5.5. Logging configuration for Confluence is specified in confluence/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties -->
                <Manager pathname="" />
              </Context>
```

The plugin, frevvo, when accessed through the browser using `http://localhost:8082` usually redirect to `http://localhost:8082/frevvo/web`

With the above configuration, when accessing `www.example.com.au/frevvo` redirects to `www.example.com/frevvo/web/static/login` - which doesn't work.

I hope the above details is clear and appreciate anyone who could give us some insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, fixed it.

Here's the solution for future reference if anyone runs into the same problem:

Apache httpd.conf:

```
ProxyPass /frevvo http://localhost:8082/frevvo
ProxyPassReverse /frevvo http://localhost:8082/frevvo
<Location /forms>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Location>
```

server.xml:

```
<Context path="/frevvo" docBase="frevvo" debug="0" reloadable="false" />
```

Comment: Oops. <Location /frevvo>, not forms